# Issue creating f2py shared object file when linking to libraries and modules

Tags: python, compilation, fortran, f2py

I am able to compile a fortran program normally with these commands:

```
ifort -O2 -I/work/GSI/include -c create_upperair.f90
ifort -o create_upperair.exe -O2 create_upperair.o -L/work/GSI/lib -lbufr
```

I am trying to take the same fortran program, but compile it as a python shared object file so that I can call this subroutine from a python script. However the f2py command is giving me issues.

Here is the command I am currently using:

```
f2py -c -L/work/GSI/lib -lbufr -I/work/GSI/include --f90flags=-O2 --fcompiler=ifort -m create_upperair create_upperair.f90
```

However that prints out errors at the end of the f2py command with something like:

```
ld: /work/GSI/lib/libbufr.a(closbf.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `nulbfr_' can not be used when making a shared object: recompile with -fPIC
```

I tried to add --f90flags="-O2 -fPIC" to my f2py command, but it didn't work either. Any ideas of what direction to go with this problem would be much appreciated.

Here is the full error at the end of f2py (note that I changed a few directory names above for simplicity):

```
ifort:f90: prepbufr_encode_upperair.f90
/glade/apps/opt/modulefiles/ys/cmpwrappers/ifort -shared -shared -nofor_main /tmp/tmpzYKBY5/tmp/tmpzYKBY5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/prepbufr_encode_upperairmodule.o /tmp/tmpzYKBY5/tmp/tmpzYKBY5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.o /tmp/tmpzYKBY5/prepbufr_encode_upperair.o -   L/glade/p/work/sdegelia/softwares/comGSI_v3.3/lib -L/glade/apps/opt/python/2.7.7/gnu-westmere/4.8.2/lib -lbufr_i4r8 -lpython2.7 -o ./prepbufr_encode_upperair.so
ld: /glade/p/work/sdegelia/softwares/comGSI_v3.3/lib/libbufr_i4r8.a(closbf.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `nulbfr_' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/glade/p/work/sdegelia/softwares/comGSI_v3.3/lib/libbufr_i4r8.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
ld: /glade/p/work/sdegelia/softwares/comGSI_v3.3/lib/libbufr_i4r8.a(closbf.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `nulbfr_' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/glade/p/work/sdegelia/softwares/comGSI_v3.3/lib/libbufr_i4r8.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
error: Command "/glade/apps/opt/modulefiles/ys/cmpwrappers/ifort -shared -shared -nofor_main /tmp/tmpzYKBY5/tmp/tmpzYKBY5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/prepbufr_encode_upperairmodule.o /tmp/tmpzYKBY5/tmp/tmpzYKBY5/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.o /tmp/tmpzYKBY5/prepbufr_encode_upperair.o -L/glade/p/work/sdegelia/softwares/comGSI_v3.3/lib -L/glade/apps/opt/python/2.7.7/gnu-westmere/4.8.2/lib -lbufr_i4r8 -lpython2.7 -o ./prepbufr_encode_upperair.so" failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: The problem isn't with your code, it's with the `libbufr_i4r8.a` library (specifically, `nulbfr_` in `closbf.o`). The symbols exported there weren't compiled to be position-independent. As a general comment, I would be surprised if the Intel Fortran compiler is ABI-compatible with the Python bindings compiled with gcc.

Comment: Tim, thanks a ton for the quick response. As a follow-up, are you saying I would need to use the -fPIC option when compiling the libbufr_i4r8.a library? And also, is there another compiler you would recommend more for this task rather than ifort?

Comment: If you can recompile the libbufr library, then yes, use the -fPIC option. It's not guaranteed that the Intel Fortran compiler won't work, but it's not guaranteed that it will. You should try it and see what happens. If it doesn't work, you'll need to use gfortran.

Comment: Hi Tim, I recompiled the libbufr library with the fPIC option and now f2py completes. However when I try to import the module from a python script, it crashes with the error:

`ImportError: /glade/p/work/sdegelia/softwares/comGSI_v3.3_testing/util/bufr_tools/testingpyversion/prepbufr_encode_upperair.so: undefined symbol: __kmpc_ok_to_fork`

(Not sure how to put that in the correct code formatting in a comment). I tried adding the -openmp and -parallel flags to my f90flags in the f2py command, but still no luck. Any idea what this could be?

Comment: That is part of libiomp5. See https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library/topic/499180 for suggested fixes.